# Ways to connect to 2007 sharepoint server from an external source

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-list

I am trying to connect to a sharepoint server from an external source. I want to be able to see and edit the lists. I have tried doing it from inside the server, but it has all pointed me to upgrading the server to Sharepoint 2010, which isn't an option currently. What other options are there for me to look into with asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint 2007 provides ASMX web services that will allow you to do this.

Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979690%28v=office.12%29). There are how-tos for getting lists and getting items from lists that will be of interest.